# Spring session redis while using custom user objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-session

I'm following this tutorial to add spring session (through redis) to my application. http://www.baeldung.com/spring-session

I add the dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and the SessionConfig.java class

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class SessionConfig extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {
}
```

I've done this on a blank project and things work great. But my current project has some custom user objects with a custom UserDetailsService and that's where things go wrong.

```
Sat Apr 07 11:21:49 EDT 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Cannot serialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.io.NotSerializableException: com.kreyzon.dollar.entity.User
```

Now, I've looked around and found suggestions to implement this:

```
@Bean
public RedisTemplate<Object, Object> sessionRedisTemplate (
        RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RedisTemplate<Object, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<Object, Object>();
    template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());

    template.setDefaultSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());

    template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    return template;
}
```

That did not work (like didn't even seem to be recognized). I also tried this

```
@Bean(name = {"defaultRedisSerializer", "springSessionDefaultRedisSerializer"})
RedisSerializer<Object> defaultRedisSerializer() {
    return new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer();
}
```

Now, this actually did *something* but still causing errors

```
Sat Apr 07 11:39:21 EDT 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Could not read JSON: Can not construct instance of org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?) at [Source: [B@4dc133; line: 1, column: 184] (through reference chain: org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl["authentication"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?) at [Source: [B@4dc133; line: 1, column: 184] (through reference chain: org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl["authentication"])
```

I've also explored other serializers like `Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer` and `GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer` but getting the same errors..

all help appreciated, thank you.

update:

I've also tried addeding this custom serializer

```
public class CustomRedisSerializer implements RedisSerializer<Object> {

    private Converter<Object, byte[]> serializer = new SerializingConverter();
    private Converter<byte[], Object> deserializer = new DeserializingConverter();

    static final byte[] EMPTY_ARRAY = new byte[0];

    public Object deserialize(byte[] bytes) {
        if (isEmpty(bytes)) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            return deserializer.convert(bytes);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new SerializationException("Cannot deserialize", ex);
        }
    }

    public byte[] serialize(Object object) {
        if (object == null) {
            return EMPTY_ARRAY;
        }

        try {
            return serializer.convert(object);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return EMPTY_ARRAY;
            //TODO add logic here to only return EMPTY_ARRAY for known conditions
            // else throw the SerializationException
            // throw new SerializationException("Cannot serialize", ex);
        }
    }

    private boolean isEmpty(byte[] data) {
        return (data == null || data.length == 0);
    }
}
```

SECOND UPDATE:

So I added `implements Serializable` to all my custom objects. That worked, go figure! (for some reason not a single post I found on the subject suggested that)

Now, my last issue persists. I'm using LDAP for authentication, and if the authentication fails, it returns an object `LdapCtx` which is not serializable and throws an error

```
Sat Apr 07 12:35:14 EDT 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Cannot serialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx
```

Is there any way to force this class to be Serializable?

UPDATE (10/22/2018):

This issue has been resolved 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5378

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're using serialization mechanism that relies on standard Java serialization, such as `JdkSerializationRedisSerializer`, you have to ensure that everything that gets stored in session implements `Serializable`. As you've experienced yourself, this is fairly straightforward for classes that are a part of your project, but can be a challenge for 3rd party classes.

I'd suggest you to look closer into JSON based serialization i.e. `Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer`. There is a [sample app](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/master/samples/boot/redis-json) withing the Spring Session codebase that demonstrates this approach.

This particular samples uses [`SecurityJackson2Modules`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/jackson2/SecurityJackson2Modules.java) to serialize Spring Security's objects. To be able to serialize your 3rd party classes with Jackson based JSON serialization, you should do something similar to what Spring Security provides.

Comment: Probably you could answer my question which is about quite close topic)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69338299/spring-security-session-object-serialization-with-securityjackson2modules