# Spring Security session object serialization with SecurityJackson2Modules

Tags: spring, spring-security, redis, jackson, spring-session

I'm using Spring Security with Spring Session which serializes the session to Redis as JSON. To make it properly working I make this Spring Session configuration. Also, I added `SecurityJackson2Modules` to the Redis Jackson serializer to make it working properly with Spring Security object.

How I understand any class serialized to session with Spring Security should be marked with an annotation like `@JsonTypeInfo` or `@JsonSerialize` if it's not in the allowed classes list of `SecurityJackson2Modules`. Classes like `Date`, `ArrayList` or `Instant` are there but `BigDecimal` is not for some reason.

How could I resolve the problem properly? Honestly I have a solution but I'm not sure if it's the most optimal.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
public class ProductDto {

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property = "type")
    @JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "BIG_DECIMAL", value = BigDecimal.class) })
    private BigDecimal price;

    // getters, setters etc.

}
```

UPD. Added an issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/10325

Comment: Why do you think that **product** and especially **price** should be part of **security** context?

Comment: Those limitations are not only about SecurityContext. They are about all the classes I want to store in the session. 

BTW. I already had a discussion about that at Spring Security GitHub

Comment: 1) You should you **proper** tools for your goal. The *SecurityJackson2Modules* is intended to support serialization of security related objects only, like authentication tokens and user info. Anything else has nothing to do with *SecurityJackson2Modules*. 2) Spring can serialize any objects in the session, but by default it uses JDK serialization. 3) If you want to serialize any objects in the Spring session in JSON format, you should configure *ObjectMapper* correspondingly. If you wish, you can even implement your own module for this...

Comment: ... But is it not correct to expect that ***Security**Jackson2Modules* will fit any **non-security** goals.

Comment: I have commented the issue at Spring Security GitHub.